# Kinect MIT demo Fuerte

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can i run Kinect MIT demonstration in Fuerte release? I found installation till Electric.

Regards,

Abhimoh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43890/kinect-mit-demo-fuerte/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a demo that hasn't been updated as far as I know.  You'll probably need to patch a few things. If you do get it to work, others would appreciate you documenting how on the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1